# Reading csv where one column is a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I have the following lines inside a csv file

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5],2145004.491585603,5.784000000019773e-05
[0 1 2 3 4 5],4986045.063898375,1.771400000016854e-05
[0 1 2 3 4 5],2185254.9265346257,1.468399999993153e-05
```

As you can see, the first entry is a list of integers. How can I read in the data, so that I end up with a list (or numpy.array), and 2 floats? I tried to use `np.genfromtxt` but I didn't know how to process the resulting bytes properly.

If there is no elegant solution, is there a better way to save the array inside one column?

Comment: It would be easier to use json instead of csv if you are dealing with data structures like arrays if you must use csv then I would ditch thhe  brackets and use a different delimeter like a semicolon or pipe symbol or an underscore even

Comment: Also a nice solution for this concrete problem could be https://jsonlines.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the list is not an actual list (no commas between items), so this should work

```py
In [1]: with open('data.csv') as f:
   ...:     reader = csv.reader(f)
   ...:     data = []
   ...:     for line in reader:
   ...:         lst_of_nums = [int(x) for x in line[0][1:-1].split()]
   ...:         data.append([lst_of_nums, float(line[1]), float(line[2])])
   ...:

In [2]: data
Out[2]:
[[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2145004.491585603, 5.784000000019773e-05],
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4986045.063898375, 1.771400000016854e-05],
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2185254.9265346257, 1.468399999993153e-05]]
```

If it was a valid list you could do

```py
import csv
from ast import literal_eval

In [1]: with open('data.csv') as f:
   ...:     reader = csv.reader(f)
   ...:     data = []
   ...:     for line in reader:
   ...:         data.append([literal_eval(line[0]), float(line[1]), float(line[2])])
   ...:

In [2]: data
Out[2]:
[[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2145004.491585603, 5.784000000019773e-05],
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4986045.063898375, 1.771400000016854e-05],
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2185254.9265346257, 1.468399999993153e-05]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is definetly simpler than what I tried. The byte thing when using `np.genfromtxt` threw me off.

I can't upvote since my reputation is too low, but I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `file` simply try this trick. I know It's ireelavent but sharing my way to read this.

Simply make data as `str` & read it.

```
import io
import pandas as pd


csv_data_as_str = '''[0 1 2 3 4 5],2145004.491585603,5.784000000019773e-05
[0 1 2 3 4 5],4986045.063898375,1.771400000016854e-05
[0 1 2 3 4 5],2185254.9265346257,1.468399999993153e-05 '''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data_as_str), sep=",",header = None)
    
print(df)
```

output

```
               0             1         2
0  [0 1 2 3 4 5]  2.145004e+06  0.000058
1  [0 1 2 3 4 5]  4.986045e+06  0.000018
2  [0 1 2 3 4 5]  2.185255e+06  0.000015
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have string of the form "[0 1 2 3 4 5]" and if the significant data are integers then:

```
lv = '[0 1 2 3 4 5]'
mylist = list(map(int, lv[1:-1].split()))
print(mylist)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This is the short version of what Ron Serruya wrote. Can't upvote unfortunately but I like your answer as well.